Storage size of stack isn't known
I've got an assignment where it's been suggested to use data hiding, primarily to use one header file instead of two. I've been following a textbook we've been provided and the compiler still can't find the size of the struct. If the fact that this is an assignment is holding you back you should know that this is not part of my grade, and that I want to know how to actually use data hiding for future reference.
Below is the fixed length array implementation of the stack, after I have edited the header file to include struct definitions, preprocessor definitions, and any structs the implementation is aggregated of:
#include <assert.h>
#include "stack.h"

#define CAP 100

struct stack
{
   ELEM arr[CAP] ;
   int size ;           // # number of elements (size of stack)
   int cap ;   // capacity
} ;

void init( stack* s )
{
        s->size = 0 ;
        s->cap = CAP ;
}

_Bool isEmpty( const stack* s )
{
        return s->size == 0 ;
}

// ... yadda yadda functionality implementation

The following code is the linked list implementation with the same changes made:
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "stack.h"

typedef struct sNode sNode ;

struct sNode
{
   ELEM data ;
   sNode* next = NULL ;
} ;

struct stack
{
   sNode* head ;
} ;


void init( stack* s )
{
        s->head->next = NULL ;
        return ;
}

// ... yadda yadda more functionality, not struct definitions

And now here is the header file after moving the definitions to the source files:
#ifndef __KS_STACK_H_
#define __KS_STACK_H_

typedef int ELEM ;

typedef struct stack stack ;

// Initialises a new stack
// Must be called before using
void init( stack* s ) ;

// return true of stack is empty
_Bool isEmpty( const stack* s ) ;

// Inserts i on top of stack
// Stack must have space
void push( stack* s, ELEM i ) ;

// Removes item, returns it
// Stack can't be empty
ELEM pop( stack* s ) ;

// Returns item at top of stack
// Does NOT modify the stack
// Stack can't be empty
ELEM top( const stack* s ) ;

#endif // __KS_STACK_H_

I am aware that many people have had similar issues, and yet the threads I've found yet have not been of use. Please do not just redirect me to a thread that may be a similar issue, but still not the same one. That does not tell me what's wrong in the context of this problem, which is actually what I'm interested in.
My question is regarding to why can the compiler not find the size of the stack implementation after attempting to use data hiding?

There doesn't seem to be a question here. What's the problem with your code?

I still don't understand the question. Please post the code that's getting the error, and the exact error message.

If you use an opaque pointer to an incomplete type, you can't get the size of the structure it points to, because the structure definition hasn't been seen.

This is normal when you're using structures for information hiding. If you hide the definition, you're hiding the size.

Yes, this is true. My issue is that you can use information hiding and still have the compiler find the size in the definition in the source code, or so I'm told. This is what I'm trying to achieve.

You were told wrong or misunderstood. If you hide it from the programmer, you're also hiding it from the compiler.

That's pretty unfortunate. I know this may be a dumb question but how could I use a struct if I'm hiding it's contents then? It sounds like I can't declare it unless it's size is known to the compiler. I'm seeing that you can typedef the struct to a pointer of itself, may that have something to do with it?

If you're hiding the contents, you have to call functions that have visibility to the definition. That's the whole point of information hiding. Since the user doesn't know the structure definition, you can change it without having to modify the caller. You just have to update the library functions.

I understand it's used for encapsulation, my issue lies in merely declaring the struct. The test file I had been using does not access contents of the struct, instead it uses it as you describe with methods who have accessibility to the data. I had still been receiving the "unknown size" error.

You can't declare a struct without defining the contents. There's no way to say "struct stack is 16 bytes, but we're not telling you what's in those bytes."

That's why we always use pointers when we're doing information hiding.

If I just have to use pointers instead of passing in the struct by reference, then I believe that's my solution. It seems I wasn't told as such, or was expected to assume so given that typedef to pointer business.

Here's a file with a forward declaration: struct foo; // forward declaration ; struct foo *foo_new(void); size_t foo_size(void); // fails ... void test_size_1(void) { printf("%zu\n,sizeof(struct foo)); } ; void test_size_2(void) { printf("%zu\n",foo_size()); } ; // fails ... struct foo * test_new_3(void) { struct foo *foo = malloc(sizeof(struct foo)); return foo; } ; struct foo * test_new_4(void) { struct foo *foo = foo_new(); return foo; }

Here's the "private" .c file: // definition struct foo { int data; struct foo *next; }; struct foo * foo_alloc(void) { ; return malloc(sizeof(struct foo)); } ; size_t foo_size(void) { ; return sizeof(struct foo); } Note that, IMO, "information hiding" is bad. Several newer style guides discourage it. With these two examples, you can see why. Use the "hiding" only in special cases.


Use pointers to the struct instead of the struct.
Members of the struct are encapsulated and will be exposed when passed back into methods in the file in which they have their definition.
Allocate new structs on the heap and return them, don't allocate to a reference.
Typdef a struct to a pointer of itself or a similar name to make working with information hiding easier for the client.

Thanks to Barmar for clarifying how information hiding is implemented to me.


why can the compiler not find the size of the stack implementation after attempting to use data hiding?

Because other source files that include stack.h only know that struct stack aka stack exists, not what it's contents are.  That means other files can't create an instance of the struct, but they can create a pointer to it.
This also means that your init function needs to allocate space for the struct and return a pointer to it rather than accepting an existing pointer.
So instead of this:
void init( stack* s )
{
    s->size = 0 ;
    s->cap = CAP ;
}

You need to do this:
stack *init(void)
{
    stack *s = malloc(sizeof *s);
    s->size = 0;
    s->cap = CAP;
    return s;
}


While this is a good and rather obvious answer in hindsight, the code you mention was provided and I'm under the impression I am not to change it.
